# (Python) Virtual env and Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, virtualenv

I'll try to explain this, hopefully it makes sense.

I had installed a virtual env a while ago in the directory: `desktop/project_website/test_project/env` to do some websites.

I also installed scrapy on the `desktop/project_website/test_project/env/Scripts` dir.

The problem is that whenever I use the command prompt to run scrapy I need to be in this *specific directory*, so all the files that scrapy creates are made in here, not in the directory where my project is (that is `desktop/project_website/Scrapy`)

So how would I would I be able to run scrapy in the dir that I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create virtualenv in any directory:

```
virtualenv some/directory
# or windows
virtualenv some\directory
```

Then you can activate that virtualenv which will change your $PATH environment variables to read python related things from virtual environments directory instead of your system's:

```
source some/directory/bin/activate
# or for windows
some\directory\Scripts\activate
```

and to deactivate type: `deactivate`

See more at [official documentation of virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/)

Once you have virtualenv activated when you call `scrapy` the scrapy of virtual environment will be called instead of system one and any packages you install via pip(if the python version in your virtualenv has it) will be installed to the virtual environment.
You can always test what will run by using:

```
$ which scrapy
some/directory/bin/scrapy
# or for windows
$ where scrapy
some\directory\bin\scrapy
```

Comment: I probably should had include this. I already activated the virtual env, and went to the `Project_website/Scrapy` directory, tried running and is not finding it

Comment: `(Test_Project) C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project_Website\Scrapy>scrapy
'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Are you sure scrapy is installed in the virtual environment? check if `virtualenv\bin\scrapy` is there.

Comment: I don't have a `bin` directory but the `scrapy.exe` file is in `C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project_Website\Test_Project\env\Scripts`

Comment: What does `where python` says? and `echo %path`?

Comment: `C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project_Website\Test_Project\env\Scripts\python.exe`  
`C:\Python\Python35\python.exe`

Comment: What about copying pasting the `scrapy.exe` file into the directory that I want. Would that work? Edit: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like the `virtualenv\Scripts` directory is not being added to your path for some reason. You can try recreating the virtual environment, maybe it's broken. You can also add virtual environment to PATH manually: `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\virtualenvironment\Scripts` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to go over it.

Comment: oh you can also probably just run scrapy by calling absolute path: `C:\virtualenv\Scripts\scrapy.exe crawl myspider`

Comment: seems like that isn't working either: `ImportError: No module named 'quotes.settings'; 'quotes' is not a package`

Comment: running `scrapy.exe` alone from other directory without all the other files that came when you install it is gonna give those errors as expected. oh well, I'll try to read the link that you posted. no worries